# How do I put the following LaTeX code in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I want to customize my title of the *article* class to align to *left* rather than defaultt centering. I found a solution to do it in LaTeX [StackExchange TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85343/left-align-abstract-title-and-authors).

The code is:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{\@title}

  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

\title{Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit}
\date{}
\author{%
    Author One$^{1}$, Author2$^{2}$\\
    $^{1}$Institution 1, I 1 City, I 1 Country\\
    $^{2}$Institution 1, I 1 City, I 1 Country\\
    \underline{$^{1}$mail@domain.com}\\
    \underline{$^{2}$mail2@domain.com }
}
```

I want to incorporate this into my **org** file which will be exported to pdf using LaTeX. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to prepend each of the lines from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother`, inclusive, with `#+latex_header:`  and include these in your org file.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to put within `(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes ...)`. Your answer will be greatly appricated.

Comment: I've not tried this but it should work, alongside the `\usepackage` directives, as it would be placed before the `\maketitle` and `\begin{document}` that org export generates.

Comment: I also think in the same lines, but yet to try. Thanks.  `\usepackage` has \\ with `org-latex-classes`. Do you know the reason?  Another thing confusing me is that `("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")`, which I am not able to make out.